# Content of class property gets cleared out before outputting to browser

Tags: php, class

I have this inside a class named `site` among other harmless stuff:

```
private 
    $notice_type = '',
    $notice_msg = '';

public function setNotice($type,$msg){
    $this->notice_type=$type;   
    $this->notice_msg=$msg;
}

public function notice($what){
    switch($what){
        case 'type': return $this->notice_type; break;
        case 'msg': return $this->notice_msg; break;
    }
}

public function clearNotice(){
    $this->notice_type='';  
    $this->notice_msg='';
}
```

I've set this class to a session like this:
`$_SESSION['site'] = new site();`

**Here's a scenario of how I use it:**
After submitting a form; I set the notification like this : `$_SESSION['site']->setNotice('success','success message');`, or error if that's the case and redirect the user somewehere using `header()`.

Then I output the message like this on the landing page:
`echo $_SESSION['site']->notice('msg');`
`$_SESSION['site']->clearNotice();`.

But; When I use the `clearNotice()`-function - the contents of both `$notice_type` and `$notice_msg` is cleared out before it gets outputted to the browser.

I need for it to stay untill the user navigates away from the page somehow. What am I missing here?

Comment: session_start() at the top of the page

Comment: `session_start()` is at the top of the page... The scripts works when I'm not using the `clearNotice()`-function. The message gets outputtet, but I stays there forever - sort of...

Comment: think you have to implement __sleep on the site class to be able to  serialize the private properties

Comment: I don't get it. Better find another way to come around this... I need to have a easy way to set and retrive messages after executions...

Comment: you are echoing `$_SESSION['site']->notice('msg');` right?

Comment: yes; First I do `echo $_SESSION['site']->notice('msg')` and right after i do : `$_SESSION['site']->clearNotice();`.

Comment: and you are only creating a new site if the session doesn't already have one i.e. `if(!isset($_SESSION['site'])) $_SESSION['site']= new site();`

Comment: yep, I have this at the top of my template :
`if (!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }  if (!isset($_SESSION['site'])){ $_SESSION['site'] = new site(); }`. It all works ok, sort of, untill I use `clearNotice()`. If I exit the script before I do `header()` and do a `var_dump()` the data is stored in the session/class...

Comment: I'm at a loss then... this should work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happend. But somehow this script started to work as expected.
I've rewritten the code over and over for a while now, and as far as I know it's just about the same as before. But anyway; This is what works now:

**site()-class:**
*This class controlls notifications as well as settings set by the user - like preffered sorting direction of data and selections worth remembering for better user experience and such.*

```
<?php
class site {
    private 
        $notice_type = '',
        $notice_msg = '';

    public function newNotice($type,$msg){
    $this->notice_type=$type;   
        $this->notice_msg=$msg;
    }

    public function notice($what){
    switch($what){
            case 'type': return $this->notice_type; break;
            case 'msg': return $this->notice_msg; break;
    }
    }

    public function clearNotice(){
            $this->notice_type='';  
            $this->notice_msg='';
    }
}
?>
```

I have a document where I configurate the entire site by setting a couple of variables to `Yes` or `No` - As in this case : `$_SITE_CLASS_site`.

```
<?php
#   check to see if session is started
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}
//
//  check if site()-class should be activated for this site
    if($_SITE_CLASS_site=='Yes'){
    #   if Yes; prevent resetting the class if it has already been started.
        if(!isset($_SESSION['site'])){$_SESSION['site']=new site();}
    //
    }
//
?>
```

I've created a template where I have this code before the page content is outputted:
*basically it just checks if there is any message to display*

```
    <?php if ($_SITE_CLASS_site=='Yes'&&$_SESSION['site']->notice('msg')!=''): ?>
            <div id="site-notice-<?=$_SESSION['site']->notice('type')?>" class="grid_12"><p><?=$_SESSION['site']->notice('msg')?></p></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Then I load the page content, and at the end I have this:
*the notice should be viewable untill the user closes it, or leaving the page. I don't want, or need, to keep the message*

```
<?php 
    if ($_SITE_CLASS_site=='Yes'&&$_SESSION['site']->notice('msg')!=''):
        $_SESSION['site']->clearNotice();
    endif;
?>
```

Now; Whenever I need to give the user a feedback on their actions - after submitting a form successfully for example - I can just do this at the end of the script:

```
$_SESSION['site']->newNotice('success','<b>Success!</b> Your request was submitted successfully...');
header('Location '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
exit;
```

It works like a charm...